# How to link to FreeGlut instead of Glut on macOS using cmake and find_package?

Tags: c, macos, opengl, cmake, freeglut

I have the latest version of macOS Big Sur, running intel based cpu, clang12, cmake 3.19 and brew. I have installed freeglut via brew.

However whenever I called find_package(GLUT) it always finds my system GLUT (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework) over the FreeGLUT brew has installed. I have tried changing the find_package to FreeGlut with no success.

I am sure its something really simple I am missing but not knowing a lot about the macOS linking process, this has me rather confused.

Here is my cmake command line being used...

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ -G Ninja
```

Here is my cmake file.

```
# Set cmake minimum version.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

# Set the project details.
set(PROJECT_NAME Project)
project(${PROJECT_NAME} LANGUAGES C)

# Treat warnings as errors.
option(WarningsAsErrors "WarningsAsErrors" OFF)

# If enabled, the post build symlink will copy instead.
option(CopyResources "CopyResources" OFF)

option(GenerateDoxygen "GenerateDoxygen" OFF)

# Disable in-source builds.
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON)
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES ON)

# Set build type to debug by default.
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
endif()

# Add Linux flag.
if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    set(LINUX TRUE)
endif()

# Define the executable.
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY C_STANDARD 11)

# Find dependencies.
# find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED COMPONENTS OpenGL)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

# Build 3rd Party Libraries
add_subdirectory(lib)

# Define source files.
add_subdirectory(src)

if (MSVC)
    string(REGEX REPLACE "/W[0-4]" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()

# Treat warnings as errors if enabled.
if (WarningsAsErrors)
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
            $<$<OR:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:AppleClang>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>>:-Werror>
            $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/WX>
            )
endif(WarningsAsErrors)

# Set compile flags.
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    # Clang
    $<$<OR:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:AppleClang>>:
        -Weverything -fcolor-diagnostics
        # Disable specific warnings.
        -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded
        -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-exit-time-destructors
        -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-weak-vtables -Wno-global-constructors>
    # GCC
    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always>
    # Visual Studio
    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/W4>
    # Enable the clang sanitizer.
    $<$<AND:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>,$<PLATFORM_ID:${SANITIZER_OS}>>:${SANITIZER_FLAGS}>
)

# Link against the clang sanitizer.
target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    $<$<AND:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>,$<PLATFORM_ID:${SANITIZER_OS}>>:${SANITIZER_FLAGS}>
)

if (LINUX)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -lm)
endif()

# Include and link against dependencies.
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE OpenGL::GL OpenGL::GLU GLUT::GLUT stb OpenAL SndFile::sndfile BigBalls::Physics lua ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

if (GenerateDoxygen)
    find_package(Doxygen)
    if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
        set(DOXYGEN_IN ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.doxyconf)

        configure_file(${DOXYGEN_IN} ${DOXYGEN_OUT} @ONLY)
        add_custom_target(doc ALL
                COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_IN}
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
                COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
                VERBATIM)
    endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
endif (GenerateDoxygen)

# Symlink or copy the resources to the binary location.
if (NOT DisablePostBuild)
    if (NOT CopyResources)
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink
                ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/res $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/res)
    else()
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/res $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/res)
    endif()
endif()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `FindGLUT` is a builtin module
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGLUT.html

looking at the source code:
see https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGLUT.cmake

so it seems to use `find_path()`

> `find_path(GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR glut.h ${OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR})`

You can try to set `GLUT_ROOT` or `OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR` as default path to help CMake to find the correct one...
ref https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html

Comment: by set you mean simply set(GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR  "/usr/...")

Comment: yes but with `set(OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR "/usr/...")` so FingGLUT will use it as hint path to find glut.h...